Buck converter capacitor ripple rating
I'm working on a buck converter that discharges a 48 V battery into a 12 V one, 20 A, 20-200 kHz and 11 μH inductor.
My first assumption (wrong?) was that the batteries at input and output would act as large capacitances, so I would not require any electrolytic capacitors on my PCB and could go away with a couple of small SMD capacitors (actually 16×2.2 μF at input and 16×2.2 μF at output). That's not the case, as the ripple is enormous during switching, over 500 mV at just 5A, didn't go further.
I've also looked at many buck designs and while they have some electrolytic capacitors at input and output, I fail to understand how they can filter the ripple at high current. Most electrolytic capacitors I find on Digikey are rated for 1-2 A at 10 kHz ripple... Based on those numbers, I would require tens of them at both input and output.
So my question is: how can “they” go away with so few electrolytic caps. I've seen many 10 A or more buck converters with only one or two electrolytics. Is the ripple current rating for an electrolytic capacitor greatly increased when it stays under 100 mV?
On a side note: Is having a lot of ceramic caps at both input and output a good idea? Except for the ripple, I find absolutely no ringing nor switching noise. It is (surprisingly?) sharp and clean.
Sorry for the crude image, I recreated what I see on my scope. I wrote VOUT instead of VIN, but you get the idea.


Thank you.

What is the controller part number?

It is also useful to share a schematic of the circuit or simulation circuits, ....

My own design controller. It switches very sharply, no noise nor ringing.  Btw: I just noticed the scope image, I wrote VOUT instead of VIN (VOUT is just the opposite, rises when switch is ON).

@Andromeda  I did add the schematic.

" Is the ripple current rating for electrolytic capacitor greatly increased when it stays under 100mV?" - not sure what you mean here. Ripple current is measured in amperes, and the ripple current applied to the Rds_on of the output capacitors is what produces ripple voltage...

Have you considered a two-phase buck? Or even a four-phase one? If you need exactly 1:4 voltage ratio, your L and C requirements would go way down with four phases.

@AdamLawrence  I'm not native english speaker. I try to explain in a different way: Is the ripple current rating (found on datasheet) of a electrolitic for a full swing from 0 to rated voltage at frequency?   Doing a full swing 0-48V @ 10KHz is surely putting more strain on the capacitor than 100mV @ 10KHz.

@winny yes, I did consider it but wanted to keep it simple with only one pwm control.

@ggadde29 I apologize, but you fundamentally do not understand how a buck converter works. The capacitor voltage will never swing from 0-48V else the output of the buck is not DC! The ripple voltage is entirely due to the current ramping up and down in the inductor being superimposed on the capacitor Rds(on). The current ramping is dictated by the size of the inductor and the switching frequency.

That, of course, I understood. But see my comment on your answer. I wasn't using RMS current to choose my capacitors (that's already halving them in my case).

It's all about the design compromises. No real magic.
Ultimately you need to design the buck for an acceptable level of di/dt, which is the source of your output ripple voltage.
If you want low ripple current, you can either operate the buck at a much higher frequency, or make the inductor much larger. That is to say, if you keep the inductor the same and increase the frequency, the ripple will be less. If you keep the same frequency and use a larger inductor, the ripple will be less.
If you are stuck with a large inductor current ramp due to other design constraints, you will need a boatload of output capacitance to ensure that the output ripple voltage is minimized.
We cannot know what constraints "they" faced in their buck designs, but e-caps take up board space and have a finite lifespan, so if there is sufficient price margin, designing a faster buck with faster MOSFETs and inductor core material that can tolerate very high switching frequency will minimize the output capacitance requirements.

Indeed no magic. I did redo my calculations for my design and it  48V -> 12V with a 11uH inductor and 200KHz switch gives a duty of ~30%. Regarding the capacitors ~470uF input capacitance would reduce ripple down to 50mV with a IRMS on the capacitors of about 10A.  My original mistake was to consider capacitor rating to match the actual buck output current while I should have used the RMS current instead (RMS current is twice as small in my case!). I still don't get why some designs have so few capacitors, possibly they don't care about overheating them.

Of course they care, otherwise the capacitors would fail prematurely and the product would have a short operational life. IPC-9592 specifies an 80% derating on the rated ripple current for electrolytic caps, and the Arrhenius-based capacitor life calculation factors in practically everything - ambient temperature, internal temperature (which is due to the ripple current), voltage stress.
